# How to update Table After Editing DataGridView Using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a C# `DataGridView`. When the user makes changes on the cell, and clicks a button, who do I make those changes in the database?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter); 
adapter.Update(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply look-up changes and iterate over them while you execute your own queries.[Save datagridView into sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016372/save-datagridview-into-sql-database)

You could also fire your action on RowLeave event.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f8741dc-5874-46e7-8665-6bda3674bafd/datagridview-automatically-save-changesaddsdeletions-as-user-moves-from-row-to-row?forum=vbide