# DataGridView has rows, but the DataSource is displaying empty

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I added rows in datagridview manually from the UI.
Now i want the datasource to fill datatable but datasouce is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have manually added rows to your GridView and you have not set DataSource so obviously datasource will be empty or null,

you just need to iterate all the rows and bind them to datatable.

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
                dt.Columns.Add("Particular", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Debit", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("Credit", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("Balance", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Summary", typeof(string));


        private void bindGridtoDataTable()
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells["Date"].Value, row.Cells["Particular"].Value, row.Cells["Debit"].Value, row.Cells["Credit"].Value, row.Cells["Balance"].Value, row.Cells["Summary"].Value);
        }
```

Comment: by using loop over each row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example of how to do this: [Save datagridView into sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016372/save-datagridview-into-sql-database)

You need to differentiate if rows have been deleted, modified or added.

```
var dataTable = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();
if(dataTable != null && dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            switch (row.RowState)
            {
                case DataRowState.Added:
                    // DO INSERT QUERY
                    break;
                case DataRowState.Deleted:
                    // DO DELETE QUERY
                    break;
                case DataRowState.Modified:
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE YOURTABLE SET TypNastaveniaID = @typ, Nazov = @title, Hodnota = @amount");
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@typ", row["TypNastaveniaID"]));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@title", row["Nazov"]));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@amount", row["Hodnota"]));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    break;
            }
        }
    ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: var dataTable = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges(); not working in my case because datasource is null

Comment: First you want to setup the binding to the source table including getting the data, please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

Answer (score 0):

Some answers here suggest you to fiddle with Rows from the `DataGridView`. **I strongly advise you not to do this, but use a BindingSource and a BindingList!**

I think the problem is because you assign your collection directly to a DataSource, instead of via a [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you have a class, say `MyClass` of which you have a sequence that you want to show in your `DataGridView`, and you want to Add / Remove / Change items from this sequence by adding / removing / changing the rows in your DataGridView you should do the following

- Get your items as `IEnumerable
- Wrap them in a BindingList
- Assign this to bindingSource1.DataSource
- Assign the bindingSource to dataGridView1.DataSource

Most of this can be done in the visual studio designer. The only thing you have to do is wrap your data in the BindingList and assign the BindingList to the DataSource of the BindingSource:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    private void InitialeDataGridView
    {
        IEnumerable<MyClass> dataToShow = ...
        this.BindingSource1.DataSource = new BindingList<MyClass>(dataToShow.ToList());
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, ...)
    {
        this.InitializeDataGridView();
    }

    private void button1_click(object sender, ...)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyClass> editedData = (BindingList<MyClass>)this.bindingSource1.DataSource;
        ProcessEditedData(editedData);
    }
}
```

You'll see all your edited data. However, your data won't be sortable. To do this, you can create a SortableBindingList, somewhere described here on Stackoverflow. However it's much easier to install [Nuget BindingListView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView/)

This will slightly change your code, but enables sorting and filtering:

Instead of a BindingList you use a `BindingListView<MyClass>`. Your code will change only slightly:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        this.myItems= new BindingListView<MyClass>(this.components);
        this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this.myItems;
    }

    private readonly BindingListView<MyClass> myItems;

    private void InitialeDataGridView
    {
        IEnumerable<MyClass> dataToShow = ...
        this.myItems = dataToShow.ToList();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, ...)
    {
        this.InitializeDataGridView();
    }

    private void button1_click(object sender, ...)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyClass> editedData = (BindingListView<MyClass>)this.bindingSource1.DataSource;
        ProcessEditedData(editedData);
    }
}
```

And presto, you're columns are sortable by clicking on the column header. See the automatic changing of the sorting-glyph in the sorted column header, you'll get that as an extra bonus.

Filtering:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.checkBox1.Checked)
    {   // show only items with Id == 0
        Predicate<MyClass> pr = p => p.Id == 0;
        this.persons.ApplyFilter(pr);
    }
    else
       this.persons.RemoveFilter();
}
```

It's that easy: add / remove / change / sort / filter: all with a few lines of code.